# Handlebars outlet contains view data, but template and partial don't

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

How can I make a `template` or a `partial` contain view data? I'm using Ember, handlebars, and requireJS. Currently, I find that only `outlets` contain view data. I'm trying  to display a property of a model in a template. Specifically, I'm trying to display the `numberFive` property of the `GraphData` model in the `graphHolderTemplate`. Using at outlet is not ideal because I want to display templates from different views on the same page, regardless of the page's URL.

ApplicationView:

```
define(['ember', 'text!templates/applicationTemplate.html'],
       function(Em, applicationTemplate) {
  var ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({

    // warning: template doesn't work here, even though defaultTemplate does.
    defaultTemplate: Em.Handlebars.compile(applicationTemplate),
  });
  return ApplicationView;
});
```

applicationTemplate:

```
<h1>{{#linkTo 'graph'}}Graph{{/linkTo}}</h1>
<h2>{{#linkTo 'graphHolder'}}Graph Holder{{/linkTo}}</h2>
<h4>outlet</h4>
{{outlet}}
<h4>template graphHolder</h4>
{{template graphHolder}}
<h4>partial graphHolder</h4>
{{partial 'graphHolder'}}
```

graphholderTemplate:

```
<h3>This is the graphHolder</h3>
<p>view.graphData.numberFive is: {{view.graphData.numberFive}}</p>
```

GraphHolderView:

```
define([ 'text!templates/graphHolderTemplate.html',
         'controllers/GraphController',
         'models/GraphData',
         'ember',
        ], function(graphHolderTemplate, GraphController, GraphData, Em) {
  // This is all that sets the template. hmmm
  Em.TEMPLATES['graphHolder'] = Em.Handlebars.compile(graphHolderTemplate);
  var graphData = GraphData.create();
  console.log("graphData.numberFive is ": graphData.numberFive);

  var GraphHolderView = Em.View.extend({
    controller: GraphController,
    classNames: ['hero-unit'],
    graphData: GraphData.create(),
  });
  return GraphHolderView;
});
```

[image: site]

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is because of a typo:

`var garphData = GraphData.create();` should be `var graphData = GraphData.create();`

EDIT: Ok it wasn't because of the typo. Next guess is that the `view` is not what you are expecting - i think it will be referencing `ApplicationView`. To be sure, try adding the following to the template:

```
<h3>This is the graphHolder</h3>
<p>view.graphData.numberFive is: {{view.graphData.numberFive}}</p>
<p>view is: {{view}}</p>
 {{log view}}
```

This should print `view.toString()` to the page and console. If you want to inspect the element further, try adding `{{debugger}}` to the template, then use js console to see what is going on.

Anyway, when you use the `{{outlet}}` helper, ember-router will fill in the appropriate template depending on your current route and context. It wraps the template in a matching `View` class if one is found.

Unlike `{{outlet}}` and `{{render}}`, both the `{{partial}}` and the `{{template}}` handlebars helper render template directly using the current context. That means they don't attempt to wrap the template in a matching `view` class.

What you probably want to use here is the `{{render}}` helper. It will render the named template in the current context using the singleton instance of the same-named controller. If a view class with the same name exists, it uses the view class.

Comment: I fixed the typo, and the graphData still does not print in `{{template graphHolder}}`, but it does in `{{outlet}}`.

Comment: Gotcha. Updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks, where does the `render` belong, and what are its arguments?

Comment: Use it in your application template where you had `{{template}}` or `{{partial}}`. args are `templateName, context, options` see api docs http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render or source code https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.3/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/render.js#L12